# Prepping for apriori

Tags: apriori

Need to further prep my data set in order to apply apriori algorithm

There are only two columns:

First column as `the transaction_id`.
Second column `is item_name` and is formatted as `c(""  "a"  "b"  "c"...)`

I run:

```
rules <- apriori(nz.mb, parameter = list(supp = 0.001, conf = 0.8))
```

I get an error:

```
Error in asMethod(object) : 
  column(s) 2 not logical or a factor. Discretize the columns first.
```

So I run:

```
nz.mb$item_name <- discretize(nz.mb$item_name)
```

I get another error:

```
Error in min(x, na.rm = TRUE) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

What is my next step with item_name so that's it's formatted correctly for apriori?

Answer (score 0):

Most Apriori implementation support Dataset like this:
a b c d 
1 1 1 0   means a,b,c are there
1 0 0 1   means  a,d are there

Either use this form or go to documentation and say the supported data for